# How to re-use formulas in a different column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel document with revenue and cost information for different companies with different nationalities. In the F column, there's the *overall revenue* of the companies, in their own currency. In the G column, I've converted the revenues to Euros. The information for the years 2020 to 2001 (at the lowest, sometimes it's a later year) is included per company.

A typical formula in the G column would be `=$F2*ExchangeRates!$B3`. This is the formula in `G2`. The G column always first references the corresponding F column, after which it multiplies it with the exchange factor that corresponds to the currency of the appropriate country valuta. Sometimes, it isn't multiplied with any exchange factor at all, because the currency of the revenues was already in Euros. So then it would be simply `=$F63` for `G63`.

Now that I've found the correct values for the *overall revenue* column of the companies in Euros, I need to find the correct values for other columns as well. I'm currently at the *CostOfSales* column - which is column I, for instance. The values in Euros are put in the column right next to it - column J.

I would prefer not go over the same laborious process yet again for the J column and others. Thus, I'd like to use the formulas of the G column. The only thing that needs to be adjusted, is that the formulas in the J column need to reference column I. So I'll use the formulas for column G, but instead of referencing column F all the time, I'd like to reference column I.

> **Question**: How does one copy and paste the formulas in the G column in such a way
> that the I column is now  consistently referenced, instead of column
> F?

Comment: Are you looking for this article? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9

Comment: @Lee That article might be very useful! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the $ from the first reference in the formula in column G, so that you have:

```
=F2*ExchangeRates!$B3
```

Now copy it and paste in column J.

Separately, when converting exchange rates, I recommend creating a column that contains the currency symbol either once per row or once per value per row (EUR, USD, GBP etc). Then, in your "ExchangeRates" sheet, create a table with two columns:

1. Currency
2. Exchange rate

Then, instead of

```
=F2*ExchangeRates!$B3
```

You would use (supposing the currency symbol is in column E and that you have exchange rates on rows 2 through 4 on the ExchangeRates sheet):

```
=F2*VLOOKUP(E2,ExchangeRates!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

The benefit here is that you aren't relying on a fixed reference to get the correct exchange rate. Rather, it is driven by whatever is on the row in the main sheet.

For those rows in EUR, you would add a row for EUR with an Exchange rate of 1:

[image]

This then means that you don't have to have a different formula on the rows that are already in EUR.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a good idea. Suppose I also have different exchange rates for different years, and a column in the revenue/cost sheet with the correct year per row. Can I then also use information for the correct year in the VLOOKUP function in the ExchangeRates sheet? And if so, how?

Comment: @MaxMuller yes it could work with diff rates for years/months/weeks etc. rather than use VLOOKUP you would want to use INDEX & MATCH, with currency down the left, and period along the top, have a go at doing it yourself if you get stuck post as a new question

Comment: Alternatively, you can change your forex table such that column A (the lookup column) has values of the form CUR-YYYY (e.g.: EUR-2020). Then, supposing the year is in column A on the main sheet, and the currency in column E as before, you would use `VLOOKUP(E2&"-"&A2,ExchangeRates!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)`